# Xamarin.Forms Failed to resolve 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, build-error

The project was working fine before just I reinstalled the OS and Visual Studio, when I build the project this error is showing.

"Failed to resolve 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler' from 'Mono.Android'. Please check your `AndroidHttpClientHandlerType` setting.   TakolA.Mobile.Android"

[image]

Comment: did you check the Http Client handler setting in the Android project?

Comment: Are you facing this issue only since VS 17.5.1 ? Cause we are having the exact same prob since we updated to latest VS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1.delete the obj folders and bin folders of every platform, then rebuild it.

2.if the problem persists, try to update your Xamarin projects with the `Android HttpClient` and `Native TLS 1.2` settings, then re-build your apps and try again.

The `Xamarin.Android HttpClient` configuration is in Project `Options` > `Android Options`, then click the `Advanced` Options button.

For more information,check: [HttpClient Stack and SSL/TLS Implementation Selector for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows).

Comment: To complement your answer: for Visual Studio Mac version 2022 I changed to AndroidClientHandler via Android Project Properties > Build > Code Generation and Runtime > HttpClient implementation. It worked!

Answer (score 5):

Android project Properties > Android Options > Advanced button > HttpClient implementation dropdown - change to Default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating to version VS 17.5.2, I did the procedure in Anton's answer, cleaned the solution and recompiled it, after that the project run normally

Answer (score 0):

I had same error in Pipeline, but locally it was building ok. Switching to Release mode and switching
Properties > Android Options > Advanced button > HttpClient implementation dropdown: Managed -> Android
solved my issue